# fill missing categorial values using dplyr group_by

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, missing-data

I have an incomplete data frame, and I want to fill missing values to match the group.

```
incomplete_table <- 
    tibble(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
       value = c("a",NA,"b","b","c","d", NA))

# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#      id value
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     a
# 2     1  <NA>
# 3     2     b
# 4     2     b
# 5     3     c
# 6     3     d
# 7     3  <NA>
```

With numeric values i can use something like this:

```
complete_table <- incomplete_table %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(value = max(value))
```

How can I fill categorial values in a similar way, using dplyr? 
This is the result I want:

```
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#      id value
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1     a
# 2     1     a
# 3     2     b
# 4     2     b
# 5     3     c
# 6     3     d
# 7     3  <NA>
```

Comment: What's the filling logic? Why the `NA` at row 7 is not filled?

Comment: I would like to fill the cells when all values in the group are the same. Group 3 has both "c" and "d", so I can't know the right value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `coalesce` the *value* column with the unique value if all the values are the same (`n_distinct == 1`) otherwise `NA`, which will leave the column as is:

```
incomplete_table %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(value = coalesce(value, if (n_distinct(na.omit(value)) == 1) na.omit(value)[1] else NA_character_))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
#     id value
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1     a
#2     1     a
#3     2     b
#4     2     b
#5     3     c
#6     3     d
#7     3  <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the coalesce function. This is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Cool. Glad it helps!